# IntelliJ: unused export default in a Vue/Nuxt app

Tags: vue.js, intellij-idea, nuxt.js, lint

I've just created a new Nuxt app and for some reason, IntelliJ is telling me that my `export default` statement is unused. If I remove it, I obviously lose the imported component (footer).

Has anyone experienced this and managed to resolve it?

Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: Try to restart your IDE - maybe it will fix the issue.
What is your IDE’s version? What is your OS?

Comment: @orhasson restarting and invalidating cache does not help. I'm on MacOS Catalina 10.15.7 and I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate 2021.1

Comment: is your exported component imported in any file (explicitly), or you are using Nuxt component auto-import with `@nuxt/components`?

Comment: @lena no, I set it to false